# Deploying a Next.js website using Netlify

Tags: next.js

I'm currently working in Next.js. My routes are currently working in development, but when I deploy via Netlify.  The routes are no longer take me to the page.  I.E. when i click about on the home page in production, the page does nothing.  I'm not sure what I need to do.

```
import css from "../pages/style/index.css";

const Nav = props => (
  <nav>
    <div className={css.flex}>
      <Link href="/">
        <div className={css.navbar_left}>
          <div className={css.full_name}>Robert Terrell</div>
          <div>Full-Stack Web Developer</div>
        </div>
      </Link>
      <div className={css.navbar_right}>
        <Link href="/about">
          <a className={css.about}>About</a>
        </Link>
        <Link href="/">
          <a className={css.portfolio}>Portfolio</a>
        </Link>

        <Link href="/skills">
          <a className={css.skills}>Skills</a>
        </Link>
        <Link href="/contact">
          <a className={css.contact}>Contact</a>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
);

export default Nav;
```

Answer (score 1):

Netlify is a static website hosting solution. It won't work with Next.js dynamic routing.

However, you can [export your Next.js website as static html](https://nextjs.org/docs#static-html-export).